# Running process after getting files in controller using Request.Form.Files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest

I've got a problem in my ASP.net Core application. I use MVC. I send a file from js to controller using:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/Test/Sing", true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

then I got it in controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Sing()
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        byte[] filedata = null;
        using (var target = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(target);
            filedata = target.ToArray();
        }

          \\some filedata processing

        return RedirectToAction("Question");
    }
```

The filedata is something that I need to process and then redirect to another action. When I put a breakpoint at the end of *using (MemoryStream)* I can see that the filedata is filled with data I need but when I want to redirect to action nothing happens. It looks like a process with the xmlhttprequest is still running on the client side and waiting for response. Am I right? How to get the file, cut the process, perform some file processing and be able to redirect to another action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually handle the redirect using `window.location.href` in success callback function of ajax/XMLHttpRequest .

If using XMLHttpRequest ,you can add listener for `load` events ,the listener must be added before the send() function:

```
function reqListener () {
    window.location.href = "url";
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

If using AJAX redirect in success callback function :

```
success: function (response) {
    window.location.href = "url";
}
```

Controller :

```
 return Json("ok");
 //Or return the url 
 return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("action", "contoller") });
```

Comment: Ok, step by step and I got another problem. Could you help me with that? I need to check the route parameter and I use `int Id = int.Parse(this.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());`. When I put it in a controller action before Json("ok") it doesn't work. Is it something that conflict with the Request?

Comment: You can use ajax to pass the parameter : http://learningprogramming.net/net/asp-net-core-mvc/ajax-in-asp-net-core-mvc/